# How Can I Find Wordpress Admin Directory

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to install a plug-in to my client's website but I don't know admin path. Probably he changed the directory with a plug-in but I can't find it.

I have admin, FTP and database login/pass. I just need to know admin directory. How can I find that?

I can't call my client at this time.

Answer (score 1):

I found it;

```
<?php echo admin_url(); ?>
```